# Vim syntax highlighting fails with autosession

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Since I've installed [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3883) VIM autosession manager (which does its job) syntax highlighting gets killed on the first buffer change after starting vim. I can restore it with

> :syntax on

but I would prefer not to have to. Maybe there is something in *~/.vim/after* I could set?

Side question: I use VIM bundle; is it still *~/.vim/after* ?

(I don't know if this matters: All I ever need syntax highlighting for are tex and lilypond files)

thanks

edit:
here's a selection from my .vimrc - possibly a lot of stuff is redundant in there.

> syntax enable
>   call pathogen#infect()
>   nmap `<Tab>` :bnext`<CR>`
>   filetype plugin on
>   filetype indent on
>   let g:tex_flavor="latex"
>   autocmd BufEnter Makefile* :set filetype=make
>   autocmd BufWinEnter *.* loadview
>   filetype off
>   set runtimepath+=/usr/share/lilypond/2.16.2/vim/
>   filetype on
>   syntax on
>   filetype plugin on

Comment: By *"VIM bundle"*, - do you mean Pathogen? And, yes; it is still `~/.vim/after`.

Comment: Is your `.vimrc` file big? Would it be possible for you to post it here? The *autosess* plugin is simply a wrapper for the builtin `:mksession`, see `:h mksession`. It does not do much beside auto-save a session file and load it. Have tested it with tex and lilypond files and they all highlights fine here.

Comment: (see edit in original answer. sorry I am a forum noob)

does it make a difference at where in the .vimrc the settings are?

Comment: Yes, generally, the order can be significant. i added an answer as it became a bit long for comment. Note that if you want to message someone use `@` followed by nick (unless it is beneath owner's question/answer - like me to you in this message.) This way the user get a *inbox* flag in status bar.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps; add these to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

If you do not have a `~/.vimrc` file, just create one:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

---

For an extreme approach you could try this suggested on the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting):

> **Highlight from start of file**
>
> For the most accurate but slowest result, set the syntax synchronization method to fromstart. This can be done with an autocmd in your vimrc:
>
> autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart

Comment: autocmd etc didn't change anything, sorry

Comment: autocmd worked for me - thanks! I narrowed the scope of the `autocmd` only to the type of file affected and reduced the amount of sync lines with `autocmd BufEnter *.css :syntax sync minlines=100`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `autosess.vim` plugin file, in `function AutoSessRestore()` I have put the `autocmd!` in comments, whatever that did (Remove ALL autocommands for the current group? it seems to have removed other autocommands too?)
I don't understand why this works (how/why should my .vimrc be sourced twice and why should that matter?), but (so far) it does. Thank you guys, I have learnt a lot.